# Python with statement: storing context

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm trying to improve (if possible) upon the DataContext class below or find alternate solutions:

```
class Store(object):

    def __init__( self, contents=None):
        self.contents = contents

class DataContext(object):

    def __init__( self, datastore ) : # datastore is of type store
        self.store = datastore

    def __enter__( self ) :
        self.temp_store = copy.copy( self.store.contents )  # Improve upon this!

    def __exit__( self, type, value, traceback ) :
        self.store.contents = self.temp_store
```

Example usage:

```
data = Store( [1,2,3] )
print "Before context: ", data.contents
with DataContext( data ):
    data.contents.append( 4 )         # Tampering with the data 
    print "Within context: ", data.contents

print "Outside context: ", data.contents
```

Output:

```
Before context:  [1, 2, 3]
Within context:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Outside context:  [1, 2, 3]
```

The `copy` can be expensive for large data structures. What would be (or is there) a clean way to only store changes to the data structure inside the context and then *undo* those specific changes to data during `exit`?

Comment: I think the answer depends on the kind of data in the store -- i.e., would it suffice to make a shallower copy?

Comment: This does not address your question, but may as well use new-style classes: `class Store(object):`

Comment: @larsmans: In this particular case a shallow copy will suffice. But I'd be interested in knowing how to deal with a deep copy situation as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Karmel: Thanks, I was being lazy in this case. It's now fixed :-)

Comment: It seems that the correct answer will depend heavily on the types of data and operations you expect. For example, it might be reasonable to add a method like `add_to_store(self, x)` that just appends x as you do above, but keeps a record of what was changed so that it can be reversed when `original_data(self)` is called. That has the advantage of not making full copies, but adds overhead in that the programmer downstream has to know that special wrapper methods should be called, rather than just append, etc. So, I guess the question is, how specialized are you willing to be?

Comment: For now, I'm willing to consider a specialized implementation. Though, I would be interested in knowing how this can be implemented generically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some sort of checkpointing. For instance, you could keep a separate structure where you would insert new elements. When you exited the context, you would need to remove these new elements from the container.

Clearly, whether this is worth compared to doing a deep cooping will depend on several factors such as:

1. The underlying container. Not all of them have the same API, so you will need to specialize the checkpointing mechanism for the different supported container types (and that may not be trivial).
2. What is the ratio of elements before entering the context vs the number of elements inserted while inside the context.

Moreover, in terms of correctness the type of container also affects the design of such a mechanism. For instance, if the container is a list you would need to remove all the elements that you inserted while in the context. On the other hand, if the container is a set, you would only need to remove them if they were not initially present.

For simplicity, let's assume you are only interested in lists and just supporting `append` operation, then a possible solution is actually very easy:

class DataContext(object):

```
def __init__( self, datastore ) : # datastore is of type store
    self.store = datastore
    self.num_added = 0

def __enter__( self ) :
    pass

def __exit__( self, type, value, traceback ) :
    l = len(self.store.contents)
    del self.store.contents[l - self.num_added : l]

def append( self, elem ) :
    self.store.contents.append(elem)
    self.num_added += 1
```

Definitely this is a very simple case, and just for adding support for removing elements from anywhere in the list, you will need to keep some sort of log of the operations performed on the list. The log could be a list of entries specifying the type of operation (insertion, deletion) and its arguments (e.g., index, data). Moreover, you will need to use a proxy or wrapper to intercept every modifying operation on the list (e.g., `append`, `extend`, `insert`, `remove`, etc.) if you want to give support for all the list operations.

If you want to go even more generic and support not only lists but other types of containers, then you would need wrappers for the operations of the different containers. For instance, for `set` you would need to support `add`, `remove`, `update`, `intersection_update`, etc. To do that you could create a class hierarchy descending from `DataContext` with the specialized operations for each type.

Anyway, as you can see, the complexity to implement this grows significantly depending on how much generic you want to be. So, probably if you just want a specific solution tailored for lists, it may pay off to implement it, otherwise it may just be better to pay the price of performing a copy of the container.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that the underlying data would need to be aware of the surrounding context and somehow update the context? Could you elaborate a bit more? Maybe an example?

Comment: @GeneralBecos I was actually thinking in a similar way to Karmel's comment. I will update my answer my a sketch of a possible solution.

Comment: You could use `with DataContext(data) as dctx` and then call `dctx.append(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `Store` using a database as the underlying storage, and simply `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: This would be the equivalent of having to store a large object and in general be slower than a copy in memory.